# Issue with using provisional profile for multiple apps?

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, provisioning-profile, code-signing-certificate

I know that we can use wildcards to have multiple apps with same provisional profile.

But we have two apps, with different domain names,
com.abc.iOSApp and com.xyz.OtheriOSApp

I tried setting the app ID as com.* but it doesn't seem to work. Is there any work around to use two apps with provisional profile.

Comment: `com.*` should work, what is the exact error message ?

Comment: We have two apps in the same solutions but I was trying to build only of them so I had provisional profile for only one app and I error was other app's bundle id was not present in the current provisional profile. I was getting is:

`Info.plist: error : Project bundle identifier 'com.abc.iOSapp' does not match specified provisioning profile '000-00-00`